# How to include a visual c++ .lib in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, visual-c++, .lib

It is possible to include a visual c++ 2005 .lib in a Silverlight project?
I wrote an ActiveX that includes a library written in visual c++ 2005, and now I want create a Silverlight plugin for cross-browser portability.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only managed runtimes supported by silverlight is c# and Vb.net so no c++ :-(.

Silverlight will however support PInvoke in version 5 but there are some tricks to it that might not fit with your usecase. It does however require elevated trust.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, Silverlight is very limited. But with the release of Silverlight 5 there seems to be support for PInvoke.

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/future/ Quite a bit down on the page.

Silverlight 5 is released later this year.